# How to change the image_picker file name

Tags: flutter

If the image_picker library return the exist file path, how to directly change it?

```
void getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
  final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    pickedFile.path; // how to rename?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use path package.**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
```

Then create a new target path to rename the file.

```
File pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    pickedFile.path; // how to rename?
  }

String dir = path.dirname(pickedFile.path);
String newName = path.join(dir, 'what ever name you want.jpg');
pickedFile.renameSync(newName);
```

Comment: `pickedFile.renameSync(newName);` need to be `File(pickedFile.path).renameSync(newName)`, thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi, if the image format wasn't ".jpg" how to use from that format?